# How to get pixel data from VideoMediaFrame.Direct3DSurface?

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, windows-runtime, hololens

I creating Unity app for Micorsoft HoloLens 2.

The app captures and shares camera video frames using *Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture* and *Microsoft.MixedReality.WebRTC*.

I got a VideoMediaFrame.Direct3DSurface(*Windows.Graphics.DirectX.Direct3D11.IDirect3DSurface*) formatted by "NV12" on *MediaFrameReader.FrameArrived* event.

But I don't know how to get pixel data from the *IDirect3DSurface* object.

I tried below:

**C# code**

```cs
[DllImport("Direct3DSurfaceAccess")]
private static extern void Direct3DSurfaceAccess([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]Windows.Graphics.DirectX.Direct3D11.IDirect3DSurface d3dSurface);

// MediaFrameReader.FrameArrived event.
private void Nv12FrameArrived(MediaFrameReader sender, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args) {
  using var mediaFrameReference = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame();

  // I could't find how to get pixel data from IDirect3DSurface using C# only.
  // Use C++/WinRT for access IDirect3DSurface as below.
  Direct3DSurfaceAccess(mediaFrameReference.VideoMediaFrame.Direct3DSurface);
}
```

**C++ code**

```cpp
void __stdcall Direct3DSurfaceAccess(const winrt::Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DSurface* d3dSurface) {
  // Here, confirmed that d3dSurface is not null.

  try {
    // Issue is here.

    winrt::com_ptr<::Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DDxgiInterfaceAccess> dxgiInterfaceAccess;
    d3dSurface->try_as(dxgiInterfaceAccess);
      // App crashes on d3dSurface->try_as.

    // Call other d3dSurface method as a test.
    winrt::Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::Direct3DSurfaceDescription desc = d3dSurface->Description();
      // Same above. App crashes on d3dSurface->Description.

    // Unreachable to here...
    // When succeeded to get the IDirect3DDxgiInterfaceAccess, read pixel data by below code.

    winrt::com_ptr<::IDXGISurface> nativeSurface;
    dxgiInterfaceAccess->GetInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(nativeSurface.put()));

    ::DXGI_MAPPED_RECT rect;
    nativeSurface->Map(&rect, DXGI_MAP_READ);
    const BYTE* pixels = rect.pBits; // Read pixel data from the pointer.
    nativeSurface->Unmap();
  } catch (...) {
    // Can't catch any exceptions.
    // App freezes and downs on HoloLens 2.
  }
}
```

I think that wrong how to marshaling *IDirect3DSurface*.

How to get pixel data from *IDirect3DSurface*?

[Reproducing sample](https://github.com/Uyawag/Direct3DSurfaceAccessInHoloLens2Example)

Comment: First thing to do is check HRESULR errors from all method calls (GetInterface, Map, etc.)

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks.
Omitted HRESULT check in this code to simplify.
In actual code, I checking that.
The case, app crashes before returns HRESULT on calling d3dSurface's method(e.g. try_as, Description).

Comment: Can you try `Direct3DSurfaceAccess([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IInspectable)] object d3dSurface);` instead

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks.
I tried UnmanagedType.IInspectable(and UnmanagedType.IUnknown too), but didn't work.
App crashed.

Comment: You should post a reproducing sample.

Comment: @SimonMourier Posted reproducing sample.
Review it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't define a C++/WinRT object pointer at the dll frontier, as at binary level, it's not a COM object (so C# is passing a COM object that's mapped to a C++/WinRT object, which is bad). What you can do instead is something like this:

```
void __stdcall Direct3DSurfaceAccess(
    IUnknown* surface, // pass a raw COM object (here I use IUnknown)
    char* message,
    size_t messageLength
) {
    try {
        // map to a C++/WinRT object here
        auto d3dSurface = convert_from_abi<winrt::Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DSurface>(surface);

        winrt::com_ptr<::Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DDxgiInterfaceAccess> dxgiInterfaceAccess;
        if (!d3dSurface.try_as(dxgiInterfaceAccess)) {
            ::sprintf_s(message, messageLength, "d3dSurface->try_as failed.");
            return;
        }

        // Call other d3dSurface method as a test.
        auto desc = d3dSurface.Description();
```

`convert_from_abi` comes from here [convert_from_abi function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/interop-winrt-abi#convert_from_abi-function)

and in this case, you can define the interop function like this:

```
[DllImport(@"Direct3DSurfaceAccess.dll")]
private static extern void Direct3DSurfaceAccess([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object d3dSurface);
```

Comment: That's great!
I did well by your answer.
Updated sample code too.
But IDXGISurface::Map returns E_INVALIDARG, however I continue research and post another question if need.
Thanks!